# is there a package similar to SHINY in R for python ?

Tags: python, r

I want to have textboxes, sliders, and buttons in the web browser that change the data visualization just like shiny does in R.

Is there something like that in python. 
Bokeh makes graphs in the browser, but they dont provide a way to manipulate the graph with sliders, textboxes etc. ?

I searched a lot but couldnt find an answer.

Comment: This may or may not solve your problem, but you may want to take a look at chaco from Enthought.  I haven't worked with it, but have a vague recollection that it may do what you need.

Comment: Bokeh is what you are looking for: http://bokeh.pydata.org/en/0.10.0/docs/user_guide/interaction.html

Comment: Meanwhile you do have another alternative in Python which is Dash: https://plot.ly/products/dash/